# Bypass top level keys in python nested dictionary to extract low level keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have a complex nested dictionary. I want to extract all "symbol" keys. I have tried functions extracting all values, .get, converting to a list, tuples, and I know I could break it down piece by piece, but I would like to know what is the most efficient, least error prone way to parse this **without calling the top level keys**. Top level keys change so creating functions to account for those is not ideal and opens up the possibility for breaking the code, so entering `symbol = map['2022-05-10:1']['303.0']['symbol']` is not what I want to have to do.

Comment: All `symbol` values or keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do get all `symbol` values in your nested dictionary you can use next example (`dct` is your dictionary from the question):

```py
print([i["symbol"] for d in dct.values() for v in d.values() for i in v])
```

Prints:

```py
['QQQ_051622C300', 'QQQ_051622C301', 'QQQ_051622C302', 'QQQ_051622C303']
```

---

EDIT: If there are missing symbols:

```py
print(
    [
        s
        for d in dct.values()
        for v in d.values()
        for i in v
        if (s := i.get("symbol"))
    ]
)
```

Comment: ok so running a loop to iterate through every value. I guess I thought there might be a dictionary method to fetch all 'symbol' keys such as dct.getkeys('symbol') which would be cleaner

Answer (score 1):

If this structure is consitent, you can use:

```py
# x is your dictionary

symbols = []

for date in x.values():
    for i in date.values():
        for j in i:
            if "symbol" in j:
                symbols.append(j["symbol"])
```

```
>>> symbols
['QQQ_051622C300',
 'QQQ_051622C301',
 'QQQ_051622C302',
 'QQQ_051622C303']
```

Or just remove `symbols = []` and replace `symbols.append(j["symbol"])` with `print(j["symbol"])` if you would rather just print the symbol key instead of saving it.